# Arduino assm ldi r26, (variable) not working

Tags: assembly, arduino

I am trying to use assembler to write some time specific routines.
things I have used before no longer seem to work, i.e.

```
uint16_t myCount;

void foo() {

  asm volatile(

    "ldi    r26,  lo8(myCount)    \n"
    "ldi    r27,  hi8(myCount)    \n"

  ::);

}
```

This assembles ok until I call foo like so

```
void setup() {

  foo(); 

}
```

then I get the error:

> undefined reference to `myCount'

obviously I am doing something silly but I cant figure out what, it all worked in 1.5, I am now trying to use Arduino 1.82

Comment: Why is `myCount` a file-scoped variable, rather than a function-scoped variable? What are you even doing with `myCount`?

Comment: @cody, myCount is a global, the assembly will eventually use it to return a value to the main programme

Comment: Global variables may have a different naming scheme. In any case, that's what constraints are for, use them instead e.g. `"x" (&myCount)`.

Comment: hi Jester, thanks for the interest unfortunately I had already tried "ldi    r26,  lo8(&myCount)      \n" thinking along the same lines but it returns 'bad expression'

Comment: That's not what you are supposed to do. You need to write what I showed into the input constraints section, and the compiler will generate the `ldi` for you as appropriate (delete those from the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables may have a different naming scheme. In any case, that's what [constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html) are for; use them instead, e.g.:

```
uint16_t myCount;

void foo() {
  asm volatile(
  "# rest of the code goes here"
  :: "x" (&myCount));
}
```

On my machine this generates the following:

```
        ldi r26,lo8(myCount)
        ldi r27,hi8(myCount)
/* #APP */
 ;  6 "t.c" 1
        # rest of the code goes here
 ;  0 "" 2
/* #NOAPP */
```

Notice that the compiler emitted the `ldi` pair for you automatically. On your machine presumably it will be slightly different, or else your original approach would have worked too.

Comment: thank you I obviously didn't understand 'constraints' properly, time to learn more I think

Comment: Added a link to GCC's documentation on constrains so that you can get started on learning more, @Hokahonay. :-)